# python webspider different between etree.ElementTree etree.fromstring etree.HTMLParser

Tags: python, web-crawler, lxml, elementtree

What function they are?

```
etree.HTMLParser()
etree.fromstring()
etree.ElementTree()
```

what different between

```
etree.fromstring(text, etree.HTMLParser())
etree.HTML(text)
```